# Adding context of two resx files

Tags: asp.net, resx

Do you know any tools to merge content of two or more resx files? At the beginning of my project development, I decided to use one resx file for every Controller in application, but now I decided to use only one file. Is it possible? They contain only strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open them in any text editor and copy out definitions from the other files into the one you intend to keep. They're just XML files, nothing special.